# Command line arguments and argc

Tags: command-line-arguments

I was just looking at executing a program with command line arguments. I see that argument count (argc) is implicit and that the computer calculates that by looking at the number of arguments I give.

I just wondered out of curiousity whether or not it is possible or me to explicitly declare the value of argc?

Comment: I assume you are talking with respect to `C`

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the late reply, I didn't even see your comment

Answer (score 0):

No, argc is passed into the main() method.   It is supplied at runtime.